# React Grid Layout with Grid Lines

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout, angular-gridster2

I want grid lines of min height and min width of cell like angular gridster(https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/) in React Grid Layout(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout).
[image]

I didn't find any example or help from anywhere.
also documentation doesn't helps much when it comes to specifying the layout of the container.